# Setup BizTalk Test Environment from Production

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We have a Production BizTalk Environment and our Test Environment went Kaput, so we are trying to copy the production environment server image and setup another Test environment.

Our Server Team successfully copied the Image of the Production server and setup the TEST Servers and the DBA's successfully backed up the Production SQL Server Database and restored in the Test SQL Server Instance.

But now when we add to the BizTalk group from the Test SQL Server Database it is still pointing to Production instance, if we stop/disable Receive Locations, Send Ports it is also stopping in Production. Please help on how to make this to work?

We also want to do the similar settings for our Disaster Recovery environment.

Comment: Wow this sounds very dangerous!  I think that during the BizTalk configuration process a lot of stuff is stored in the various databases that points to other databases, servers etc.  Did you try unconfigure and then reconfigure?  Personally I don't think I'd take the risk.

Comment: It would be safer to do a clean install of BizTalk and then export the applications in binding files from Prod and import them into your new test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to do this (even with lots of people advising you not too).
The steps you need to take can be found here **[How to Move the BizTalk Server Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547833%28v=bts.20%29.aspx)** (BizTalk 2006R2)
The steps you have to do to point to the new Test BizTalk server to your restored databases, which is the step that you've missed out and why it is still pointing to your Production database.

For BizTalk 2010 it would be
 **[How to Restore Your Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546753.aspx)** and you will also want to read **[Moving the BizTalk databases (part 2)](http://blogical.se/blogs/mikael_sand/archive/2013/04/04/moving-the-biztalk-databases-part-2.aspx)**.

Comment: thanks for the insight, I agree it is dangerous but we are in a situation where nothing is an option.